# how to add add config to this script?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

```
# Make sure you have the required Azure PowerShell modules installed
# Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force

# Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Define the input JSON-like structure
$jsonInput = 'your-json-string-here'
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonInput

# Function to get resource group name by ID substring
function Get-ResourceGroupName($idSubstring) {
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$idSubstring*" }
    return $resourceGroups.ResourceGroupName
}

# Function to get function app config settings
function Get-FunctionAppConfig($functionAppName) {
    $appSettings = Get-AzWebApp -Name $functionAppName | Select -ExpandProperty SiteConfig.AppSettings
    return $appSettings
}

# Process each resource group and function app
foreach ($rg in $data.resourceGroups) {
    $resourceGroupName = Get-ResourceGroupName -idSubstring $rg.id
    foreach ($app in $rg.functionApps) {
        $actualConfig = Get-FunctionAppConfig -functionAppName $app.name
        foreach ($key in $app.configSettings.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
            $expectedValue = $app.configSettings.$key
            $actualValue = $actualConfig | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $key } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            $match = $actualValue -eq $expectedValue
            $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ResourceGroup = $resourceGroupName
                ResourceType  = "Azure Function App"
                ResourceName  = $app.name
                ConfigKey     = $key
                ConfigValue   = $actualValue
                ExpectedValue = $expectedValue
                Match         = $match
            }
            $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
    }
}
```

tried with azure func apps. i need to be able to to to the same with azure data factory so that the the key-value pairs int e settings and config can be listed and compared for reconcilation

Comment: `# Function to get function app config settings using a name substring
function Get-FunctionAppConfig($functionAppNameSubstring) {
    $functionApps = Get-AzWebApp | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$functionAppNameSubstring*" -and $_.Kind -eq "functionapp" }
    $configs = @()

    foreach ($app in $functionApps) {
        $appSettings = $app | Select -ExpandProperty SiteConfig.AppSettings
        $configs += [PSCustomObject]@{
            FunctionAppName = $app.Name
            ConfigSettings  = $appSettings
        }
    }

    return $configs
}`

Comment: `

function Get-ResourceGroupName($idSubstring) {
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$idSubstring*" }
    if ($resourceGroups.Count -eq 1) {
        return $resourceGroups.ResourceGroupName
    } elseif ($resourceGroups.Count -gt 1) {
        Write-Warning "Multiple resource groups found for ID substring '$idSubstring'. Consider specifying more precisely."
    } else {
        Write-Error "No resource groups found for ID substring '$idSubstring'."
    }
}


`

Comment: https://draft.blogger.com/u/1/blog/posts/329533540054315333?pli=1

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? @Martin

Answer (score 0):

> Need to be able to do the same with azure data factory:

To achieve the same functionality for data factory,
use [`Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2linkedservice?view=azps-11.3.0),
[`Get-AzDataFactoryV2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2?view=azps-11.3.0) PowerShell commands which lists all the related information of data factory and the complete PowerShell script is detailed below.

```
$jsonInput = Get-content -path "/home/xxx/modifiedjson.json"
$data = $jsonInput | convertFrom-json
function Get-ResourceGroupName($idSubstring) {
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq "*$idSubstring*" }
    return $resourceGroups.ResourceGroupName
}
$resourceGroupName = "xxxx"
$dataFactoryName="xxxxdfactory"
# Function to get Data Factory config settings
function Get-DataFactoryConfig($dataFactoryName, $resourceGroupName) {
    $adf = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name $dataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $adfConfig = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName | Select -ExpandProperty Properties
    return $adfConfig
}

# Process each resource group and Data Factory
foreach ($rg in $data.resourceGroups) {
    $resourceGroupName = Get-ResourceGroupName -idSubstring $rg.id
    foreach ($adf in $rg.dataFactories) {
        $actualConfig = Get-DataFactoryConfig -dataFactoryName $adf.name -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
        foreach ($key in $adf.configSettings.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
            $expectedValue = $adf.configSettings.$key
            $actualValue = $actualConfig | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $key } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            $match = $actualValue -eq $expectedValue
            $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ResourceGroup = $resourceGroupName
                ResourceType  = "Azure Data Factory"
                ResourceName  = $adf.name
                ConfigKey     = $key
                ConfigValue   = $actualValue
                ExpectedValue = $expectedValue
                Match         = $match
            }
            $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]